# Not sure about a convergent series

Tags: convergence-divergence

I solved this series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2\ln n}$$ wit Condensation Test and I got now $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^nnln(ln(2))}$$ 
 Can I use now a geometric series like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1 {2^n}$ with comparasion test for say that  $\frac{1}{2^nln(ln(2))}<\frac 1 {2^n}$ and get the conclusion that the series is Convergent?

Thanks

Comment: What is nlnlnlnlnllnln

Comment: @SahibaArora Ask google translate to see what it sounds like xD

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, I'm sorry?

Comment: @SahibaArora You can ask google translate to try and pronounce that ***thing*** you have there.  I mean, you asked for what it was, so I thought you'd be interested in what it sounded like.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I think your comment is intended for Salahamam_Fatima.

Comment: @SahibaArora My gosh, you are right.  My bad xD

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Please read the above x3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, factor out the $\frac{1}{\ln \ln 2}$ and the comparison $\frac{1}{2^n n} < \frac{1}{2^n}$ will work, because $$\frac{1}{2^n n} < \frac{1}{2^n} \implies 2^n n > 2^n \implies n > 1$$ and  $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ is a convergent geometric series.

Comment: The problem is that I have ln ln(2), and is <1. Is that a problem?

Comment: @arcilli yes see my edits

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima yes, but i'm not sure if I follow what you're saying :)

Comment: @Dando18, thanks, I understand! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier to observe that $\dfrac{1}{n^{2}\sqrt{n}}<\dfrac{1}{n^2 \log (n)}$ for any $n\ge 2$ because $\sqrt n>\log n$ and $\dfrac{1}{n^{2+\frac12}}$ converges

so the given series converges

hope it helps